# Big Questions in First Order Logic

Tags: computability, first-order-logic

if $\Sigma$ is a r.e set  (half decidable) of sentence in first order logic,

> > the set of logical result of $\Sigma$  is Recursively Axiomatizable.

why this is false? or maybe it's true? pleas correct me.

Comment: Do you actually mean that "The set of logical results of $\Sigma$ is Recursively Enumerable"?

Comment: @KyleGannon Recursively axiomatizable means has a recursive set that generates the same logical results.

Comment: i think all logical inference result from Σ , it's a 2009 Final Exam, without any description.

Comment: yes, i think the William is right.

Comment: @William: Thanks

Comment: The original question makes sense, the second question suggested by Kyle is much easier.

Comment: Dear @ReneSchipperus, would you please submit as an answer?

Comment: Sorry I dont have an answer to your question, what was the level of the exam ? What tools from recursion theory were being used ?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Sigma$ is recusively enumerable, let $f : \omega \rightarrow \omega$ be a computable function that surjects onto $\Sigma$. Let $\phi_n$ be a computable listing of first order formula in your particular language.

Now define $\Gamma$ as follows:

$\phi_n \in \Gamma$ if and only if there is a $p$ and there is a $k < n$ such that $\phi_n$ takes the form $\bigwedge_{i < p} f(k)$, i.e. the conjection of $f(k)$ $p$ many times.

Clearly $\Gamma$ is recursive.

For every $n$, if you choose $m$ large enough, there is a $n' > n$ such that $\phi_{n'}$ is $\bigwedge_{i < m} f(n)$. Then by definition, $\bigwedge_{i < m} f(n)$ in $\Gamma$.

Clearly the the logical consequences of $\Gamma$ and $\Sigma$ are the same since for all $\varphi \in \Sigma$, there exists some $p$ such that $\bigwedge_{i < p} \varphi$ is in $\Gamma$; and for every element $\psi \in \Gamma$, there is a $p$ and an element $\varphi \in \Sigma$ such that $\psi = \bigwedge_{i < p} \varphi$. That is to say, $\Gamma$ consist of just multiple conjuncts of elements of $\Sigma$.

Comment: you means this sentence that mentioned on question are true?

Comment: By the way, this is a classical result. The argument is known as Craig's trick. It first appeared in W. Craig, *On axiomatizability within a system*, The Journal of Symbolic Logic, **18**, (1953), 30–32.

Comment: @OpiijasFuchis Yes, it is recursively axiomatizable.

Comment: Dear @William, can say your idea about (1) if Σ is complete, then the set of logical result is recursive (decidable). (2) only if Σ is recursive (decidable), then the set of logical result of Σ is recursive.

Comment: (2) is false. There are many counterexamples. (1) is true. The idea is that if $\Sigma$ is complete, every formula either its or its negation is provable. Then just search simultaneously for the proof of it or its negation. Eventually you will find a proof of one or the other.

Comment: Dear @William, would you please some search keywords or exactly change my question that use standard keyword? thanks.